# HTC HD2 Can't start certain App from SD with CyanogenMod Gingerbread 2.3.3

Tags: applications, 2.3-gingerbread, cyanogenmod, external-sd, htc-hd2

I've installed [BOYPPC-SHIFTPDA DESIRE HD V7 & GINGER 2.3.3_V9](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=967353) (NAND [DAF]Clean) on HTC HD2, everything is fine except I can't run some app (almost all app large than 1Mb) from SD (eg. Angry Birds from Market). I can run the app if it is installed on the phone memory, and I can install or move the app to SD, but when I click the icon, it shows "application…stopped unexpectedly". My friend running another mod with Ginger 2.3.2 don't have this problem. Is there anything I can do to make it work? Or this is the thing beyond my control?

Comment: There has been a V10 and a V11 released since yours, nothing's mentioned in the change notes but it is possible this issue's been fixed in one of those

Comment: @GAThrawn, V10 and V11 released in a week after V9 and boyppc(the developer) was saying app2sd is not supported, could this be the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like those ROMs just don't support App2SD.  Someone else was asking about it: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=12193603&postcount=453

Comment: @Matthew, thank you, can you recommend another rom?

Comment: I don't have an HD2 myself, so I don't know from experience, but this one has app2sd and is built from CyanogenMOD so I would expect it to be good: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=769026

Comment: do I need to format sd with a EXT4 partition in order to use app2sd? if that is the case, than I don't think it was the issue, as my friend on another mod never formated his....

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that, app2sd works on my Galaxy S and my card is the default FAT partition.  But I don't know how CM works.

Comment: Thank you Matthew, I'll update to another ROM with App2SD support and have a try.

Comment: @Matt. The ROM you suggested does work well on my hd2 and solve the problem I had before. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great, glad to hear it!